# Blender File Changes Color After Move

Tags: rendering, color

My blender materials change color if I move the file to a different computer. I have tried different ways of moving the file, but the result is always the same).

Technically, the materials are fine (they remain correct after move), but they render incorrectly (see Image).

I have tried packing the external data and it doesn't help.

Thoughts?  Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see this behavior is because the link to the texture is broken. I found that Blender has difficulty "remembering" the location of the texture when moving a file or even opening the same file on a different computer. Relink the textures should fix your problem.